# How to use GetKeyState command with If Else?

Tags: autohotkey

This does not work, The `Else` block always triggers as soon as I hold down `Xbutton2`

```
XButton2::
If GetKeyState("LButton", "P")
    {
        Tooltip, LButton down
    }

Else
    {
        Tooltip, LButton Not down
    }
```

Below is another attempt I made sadly, the same thing as above happens.

```
XButton2::
GetKeyState, state, LButton

if (state = "D")
   { 
    Tooltip, LButton down
   }
else
    {
        Tooltip, LButton Not down
    }
```

Comment: You're missing [Return](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Return.htm) to stop code execution.

Comment: The code appears to do exactly what it is programmed to... [If the `Left Mouse Button` is held down at the moment when `Mouse Side Button 2` is pressed, display the tooltip "LButton down". Otherwise, if the `Left Mouse Button` was not held down at the moment `Mouse Side Button 2` was pressed, display "LButton Not down"] If this was not what was intended, please clarify what the expected behaviour would be so we can help you out

Comment: @spyre Yes that is exactly what happens. I am intending for if `Mouse Side Button 2` is down then `Lbutton` is always triggers Tooltip `LButton Not down` Instead the opposite is happening. I just realized my tooltip messaging does not make sense. Essentially I would like one thing to happen for just `Xbutton2` on its own and another thing for `Xbutton2` + `LButton` being pressed together.